# Will a Postgres GIN index allow you to achieve the performance characteristics of a "Columnar" database?

Tags: postgresql

I am interested in gaining the performance effects of columnar storage without having to standup a columnar database e.g. AWS Redshift. Can I achieve comparable speed up in Postgres by leveraging GIN indexes? The GIN index type appears to be an inverted index based on unique column values, much like a columnar database would have.